# Programmatic access to a sound played through OpenAL

Tags: audio, openal

I am working with an application that uses OpenAL API quite extensively. In particular, there are multiple sound sources, non-trivial listener filters, etc.

I want to be able to run this application significantly faster than real-time. At the same time, the sound must be saved for later postprocessing. Is there a way to access the OpenAL output programmatically (virtually) without ever playing the sound on the real playback device?

Ideally, I'd like to have access that would be played during every `tick` of the main loop of my application. Normally one tick corresponds to one rendered frame (e.g. 1/30th of a second). But in this case we would be running the app as fast as possible.

Answer (score 2):

We ended up using OpenAL Soft to do this. Example:

```
#include "alext.h"
LPALCLOOPBACKOPENDEVICESOFT alcLoopbackOpenDeviceSOFT;
alcLoopbackOpenDeviceSOFT = alcGetProcAddress(NULL,"alcLoopbackOpenDeviceSOFT");
```

replace your default device with this device

```
ALCcontext *context = alcCreateContext(device, attrs);
```

Set the attrs as you would for your default device

Then in the main loop use:

```
LPALCRENDERSAMPLESSOFT alcRenderSamplesSOFT;
alcRenderSamplesSOFT = alcGetProcAddress(NULL, "alcRenderSamplesSOFT");
alcRenderSamplesSOFT(device, buffer, 1024);
```

Here the buffer will store 1024 samples. This code runs faster than real-time, therefore you can sample frames every `tick`

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to do your required functions with the audio data prior to its being shipped to OpenAL? I've done a lot with javax.sound.sampled when it is untethered by the blocking write() method in `SourceDataLine`, especially when saving to file rather than playing back.

From what little I know about OpenAL, there is also a blocking process occurs when data is shipped, with a queue of arrays that are managed. I've been meaning to look into this further...

(Probably not being very helpful here. Apologies.)

Comment: Essentially I have an existing application that I want to run faster than realtime. Among other things, I want to capture the sound generated by the application. The sound subsystem is quite complex and involves multiple emitters, filters, doppler shifts etc. All of this is handled by OpenAL. 

Ideally I'd like to extract the sound samples that are normally sent to the sound card and get runtime access to these samples as the application is executed.

Comment: It might be possible to intercept the data before the point where buffers are shipped off for playback. My starting point would be to look for that point. It's frustrating, so often sound libraries do not have hooks for working directly with the data: e.g., Java Clip, JavaFX sound, most libraries for mp3 & ogg/vorbis. Exceptions: Java's SourceDataLine & Android. I wanted to write a wrapper to allow sending output from my sound library to LWJGL and again ran into this roadblock. I started working on the wrapper but put it on the back burner after running into complexities. Should revisit.